# How to embed vue 3 + vite app as widget to third-party site html file?

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I created a widget project using vite, made a build. Then created a separate project, and I'm trying to connect the build from the widget project to it, but I can't... Can someone provide an example or suggest a resource?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far to make us better understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do it https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

**Widget project -> vite config file**

```
build: {
    lib: {
        entry: './src/main.ts',
        name: 'Widget',
        fileName: 'widget',
        formats: [ 'es' ]
    }
},
define: {
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
}
```

**Widget loader script for other project**

```
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost:1234/dist/style.css');
    document.head.appendChild(link)

    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.setAttribute('id', 'app')
    document.body.appendChild(div)

    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.async = true
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost:1234/dist/widget.umd.js')
    document.body.appendChild(script)
```